# Rails date and time is off on my local machine in created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

ok this is very strange.

My computers clock is correct, but whenever I output a created_at field in the database and format it, the day/time are off my several hours...

Is there some Rails 3 localhost type setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your `config.time_zone` configured? You can set it to the right timezone in application.rb (Rails3) or environment.rb (Rails") (check http://mad.ly/2008/04/09/rails-21-time-zone-support-an-overview/).

Answer (score 3):

Rails 3 stores timestamps as UTC in the database.  When you pull it out it will format according to `config.time_zone` in your config/application.rb.

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > Thing.create
 => #<Thing id: 1, name: nil, created_at: "2010-10-10 17:57:47", updated_at: "2010-10-10 17:57:47"> 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > Thing.first.created_at
 => Sun, 10 Oct 2010 13:57:47 EDT -04:00
```

Note the difference between created_at in the db and how it is displayed.